# Compare two mixed-effect models differing on the nested effect

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, model-comparison, glmmtmb

I need to compare two models with repeated measures (I'm using using lme4 or glmmTMB for the random effects)

```
Y ~ var1 + var2*var3 + (1|Country)
Y ~ var1 + var2*var3 + (1|Country/ID)
```

Where ID is the identifier of the person, nested to the country.

What test should I use here to quantify how much one is better than the other? (If possible something included on R or one of its packages).

I don't know if just using the AIC is right here or if I need to use the ROC curve or other alternative.

In fact my outcome is binary, I'm using a logit model with random effects, but I think the problem is similar.

Comment: https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#testing-significance-of-random-effects Short version: don't do it.

Comment: OK, then I just post the two results as separate without comparing them?

Comment: No, you choose the model based on what makes sense a priori and then stick to it. If it's repeated measured design with multiple measurements per ID, then that's an a priori reason to have ID as a random effect.

Comment: My model makes sense with both decisions (because the real situation is a mix of both but we don't know how much of each) and I want to post both, explain the difference and say that one produces better statistical results.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes to mind is that if you have repeated measurements within `ID` then you should fit random intercepts in order to adjust for the non-independence of observations within each `ID`. The study design requires it (or another method to handle clustering).

If there is evidence that the variance of the random intercepts is zero, then this should be reported. However, testing for zero variance of random effects is not straightforward. The easiest approach is simply to use a likelihood ratio test (e.g. the `anova()` function in R) however it is important to understand that testing a variance of zero in this way is conservative. A better approach is to use a simulation-based approach such as the one implemented in the `RLRsim`package (which is co-authored by one of the authors of the `lme4` package).